# Word Wrap in HTML

Tags: php, css, html

I have a long text string that needs to be displayed after being fetched from database. I'm able to display it on the screen, however when the string is too long, the complete string is not being displayed. Here is my code:

```
echo '<td>'.'<input type = "text" class="form-control" disabled = "disabled" id ="fieldText" name = "fieldText['.$row["ID"].']" value = "'.$row["fieldText"].'">'."</td>";
```

Not sure what changes need to be made in order to display the complete string. Can someone help please.

Comment: Did you check the length of the inserted string from the database? VARCHAR(x). Maybe the x is not long enough. Check if the VARCHAR of the fieldText is long enough.

Comment: Increase the width of the input using css. Use the style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try use textarea. replace you input field with a textarea tag with the same name

```
echo '<td>' . ' <textarea class="form-control" 
     name = "fieldText['.$row["ID"].']" 
     value = "'.$row["fieldText"].'" 
     cols="40" rows="4" ></textarea>' . "</td>";
```